# Unsupported API version on Spigot 1.14 snapshot

Tags: java, minecraft-modding, bukkit

I'm (trying to) develop a plugin for Spigot Minecraft 1.14.2. I have tried putting both `api-version: 1.14.2` and `api-version: 1.14.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT` in my `plugin.yml` file however it always comes up with the following error:

```
org.bukkit.plugin.InvalidPluginException: Unsupported API version 1.14.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_14_R1.util.CraftMagicNumbers.checkSupported(CraftMagicNumbers.java:252) ~[spigot-1.14.2.jar:git-Spigot-df0eb25-649921e]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader.loadPlugin(JavaPluginLoader.java:131) ~[spigot-1.14.2.jar:git-Spigot-df0eb25-649921e]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugin(SimplePluginManager.java:333) ~[spigot-1.14.2.jar:git-Spigot-df0eb25-649921e]
    at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.loadPlugins(SimplePluginManager.java:252) [spigot-1.14.2.jar:git-Spigot-df0eb25-649921e]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_14_R1.CraftServer.loadPlugins(CraftServer.java:347) [spigot-1.14.2.jar:git-Spigot-df0eb25-649921e]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_14_R1.CraftServer.reload(CraftServer.java:803) [spigot-1.14.2.jar:git-Spigot-df0eb25-649921e]
    at org.bukkit.Bukkit.reload(Bukkit.java:576) [spigot-1.14.2.jar:git-Spigot-df0eb25-649921e]
    at org.bukkit.command.defaults.ReloadCommand.execute(ReloadCommand.java:27) [spigot-1.14.2.jar:git-Spigot-df0eb25-649921e]
    at org.bukkit.command.SimpleCommandMap.dispatch(SimpleCommandMap.java:149) [spigot-1.14.2.jar:git-Spigot-df0eb25-649921e]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_14_R1.CraftServer.dispatchCommand(CraftServer.java:707) [spigot-1.14.2.jar:git-Spigot-df0eb25-649921e]
    at org.bukkit.craftbukkit.v1_14_R1.CraftServer.dispatchServerCommand(CraftServer.java:692) [spigot-1.14.2.jar:git-Spigot-df0eb25-649921e]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.DedicatedServer.handleCommandQueue(DedicatedServer.java:433) [spigot-1.14.2.jar:git-Spigot-df0eb25-649921e]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.DedicatedServer.b(DedicatedServer.java:397) [spigot-1.14.2.jar:git-Spigot-df0eb25-649921e]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.MinecraftServer.a(MinecraftServer.java:956) [spigot-1.14.2.jar:git-Spigot-df0eb25-649921e]
    at net.minecraft.server.v1_14_R1.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:801) [spigot-1.14.2.jar:git-Spigot-df0eb25-649921e]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_212]
```

however I am using the correct API version. Whenever I change the `api-version` in `plugin.yml` the error message changes accordingly.

What have I done wrong?

EDIT: https://termbin.com/u5a8 - full server log
plugin.yml:

```
name: choruschaos
main: com.cospox.choruschaos.main
version: 0.1
api-version: 1.14.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT
commands:
```

main.java:

```java
package com.cospox.choruschaos;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class main extends JavaPlugin {
    // Fired when plugin is first enabled
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
    }
    // Fired when plugin is disabled
    @Override
    public void onDisable() {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove everything after 1.14, it should look like this:

```
api-version: 1.14
```

alternatively just remove it. It doesn't really serve any purpose right now.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that in the morning (it's a bit late for me). If I remove the line it also gives an error, something like "api version not specified". Could this be to do with my debug setup? I'll test it tomorrow